# SwiftUI - Dot indicator immediately after end of text

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I wish to show dot indicator on top trailing immediately after text ends. Currently the dot indicator is aligned to top trailing, but is being displayed at the end of the list row. Sharing code and screenshot below:

***Code:***

```
HStack {
    Text("Building O")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
        .overlay(alignment: .topTrailing) {
            Image(systemName:"circle.fill").resizable().foregroundColor(.blue).frame(width: 5.0, height: 5.0)
        }
    Spacer()
    Image(systemName: "checkmark").padding(.trailing, 5.0).font(.body).foregroundColor(.blue)
}
```

***Screenshot:***

[image]

In the screenshot above, I added red dot via photo edit, but basically I wish to show the blue dot in place of red dot i.e. immediately after text ends and not at the end of the list cell. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Placing of modifier in swiftui is very crucial. It will change your output if you place them in the wrong place.

```swift
{
        HStack {
            Text("Building O")
                .padding(.trailing, 7.0)
                .overlay(alignment: .topTrailing) {
                    Image(systemName:"circle.fill").resizable().foregroundColor(.blue).frame(width: 5.0, height: 5.0)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: "checkmark").padding(.trailing, 5.0).font(.body).foregroundColor(.blue)
        }
    }
```

If you want to put extra space you can adjust the padding inset.
Attaching a screenshot for your ref, Tried on Xcode 14.3.
[image]

Comment: This worked. Thanks! I am still learning about how to place modifiers correctly.